# Node Express - Two angular apps (Front and CMS)

Tags: node.js, express

Im new to node and express and trying to figure out how to seperate my node server into two apps. One for the front and one for the cms.. For example '/' would show the front app and then /admin would show the admin section. I want two be able to separate the apps so each apps gets its own resources..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can handle url in server-side and route different static directories to request.

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + "/public/user-side/"));
app.use('/admin', express.static(__dirname + "/public/admin-side/"));
```

Comment: was trying that last night, but couldnt get it to work.. will try and again and let you know..