# two angular apps in a express app (Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment:)

Tags: angular, express

Hi (sorry for my english is not my native language)

As many I have an angular app running in express and decided to use a separate angular app for the the admin and users (basically because I was getting too much routes in the navigation bar)
I have now two apps running fine when I run them separately using "ng serve" (each with their own navigation). The problem came when I tried to put both apps into express.

I did as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33775990/node-express-two-angular-apps-front-and-cms) ,

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'gbv'))); //the output from "ng build" app1
app.use('/admin',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin'))); // the output from "ng build" admin and users app
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index'); //also use this index file to send files
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

The routes/index.js file has the following

```
router.route('/')
.options( (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
})
.get( (req, res, next) => {
    //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../gbv/index.html"));
});

...
router.route('/admin')
.options( (req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(200);
})
.get( (req, res, next) => {
     //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });

  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"../admin/index.html"));
  return;

});
```

I get to my site http:localhost/  with no problems but when I do http:localhost/admin I got this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'
```

And the same navigation from the first app1 remain

Sadly I can't show pictures yet...

The strange is that checking the network console, I can check that the file does get sent.
It seems like if the navigation from the first app1 remains, instead of bringing the app2's.
I suspect that has something to do with the fact that the two files are called index.html, which would be causing the confusion. I tried to change the name of the output files before I do "ng build". But angular doesn't allow me to do so.

I'm using express 4.16.1
angular 10.2.2

Did anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

xD for some reason it works by changing to

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'gbv')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'admin')));
```

and using

```
ng build --output-hashing all
```

when constructing the build in angular.